# Unable to use Netmiko to generate fcalias

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to be able to first create an fc_alias before eventually adding the code to make the zone and zone_set. I'm able to get into the device along with produce the initial part of the command to make the fc_alias. When I add the str value(fc_alias) along with float value(vsan_id) it doesn't interact well together. I can't seem to find a way around this to be able to create the fc_alias.

```
def fc_alias(self):

    # store TEST switch info

    cisco_asa = {
        'device_type': 'cisco_nxos',
        'ip': 'xxx.xx.xx.xxx',
        'username': 'admin',
        'password': 'xxxxx',
    }
    # Connect to TEST switch using Netmiko function "ConnectHandler"
    net_connect = ConnectHandler(**cisco_asa)
    print(net_connect.find_prompt())
    #move to config menu
    net_connect.config_mode()
    print(net_connect.find_prompt())

    #set fc_alias
    fc_alias = "testname"
    vsan_id = ("1")
    output = net_connect.send_config_set("fcalias name","fc_alias","vsan",vsan_id)
    print(output)
```

Here is the error being produced

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Switches.py", line 43, in <module>
main()
File "Switches.py", line 39, in main
TestSwitch()
File "Switches.py", line 33, in __init__
str.vsan_id = ("1")
TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'str'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there was a few issues. One is that I had my variable fc_alias in quotes so it wasn't being called properly. I was also using the wrong command(net_connect.send_config_set) when I should have been using net_connect.send_command. I was also trying to use a string and a float and it was unable to automatically convert them both to a string. In order to convert them both to string I stored it in a variable before sending the command.

```
def fc_alias(self):

# store TEST switch info

cisco_asa = {
    'device_type': 'cisco_nxos',
    'ip': 'xxx.xx.xx.xxx',
    'username': 'admin',
    'password': 'xxxxx',
}
# Connect to TEST switch using Netmiko function "ConnectHandler"
net_connect = ConnectHandler(**cisco_asa)
print(net_connect.find_prompt())
#move to config menu
net_connect.config_mode()
print(net_connect.find_prompt())

#set fc_alias
vsan_id = ("1")
fc_alias = "testname"
fc_alias2 = ("fcalias name "+fc_alias+ " vsan " +vsan_id)
output = net_connect.send_config_set(fc_alias2)
print(output)
```